# Right to left graph labels for right-to-left languages

Tags: charts, internationalisation, rtl

When building a graph or chart for use by right-to-left languages such as Arabic should the labels also change? For instance it is generally accepted in my English speaking culture that lower numbers are on the left and higher on the right

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
2001        2002        2003        2004        2005
```

Would this flip to look like?

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
2005        2004        2003        2002        2001
```

I hunted around to find examples but I could find examples of both graphs which maintain the left-to-right ordering even when presented in an Arabic context and those which switched.

Comment: See this related post (and my answer) for a few links that generally touch on this topic: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36754/original-design-choice-of-back-and-forward-directions/36760#36760

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is don't put years in reverse order for Arab audience or other languages like Hebrew or Urdu which is written right to left.

Numerals in every language are written left to right and putting lower values on the left and higher on the right is standard. Considering that, it is a standard to have lower values on the left and higher values on the right which also holds true for years.