# Why is backslash called BACK slash when arguably it points forward?

Tags: terminology

This is a backslash [\](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash).

If you read the slash from left to right it starts at the top and goes down - hence it is a downslash.

If you read the slash from top to bottom it starts on the left - which in our culture represents back direction - and continues to the right - which represents the forward direction. Hence it is a forward slash.

So why do we call in a backslash?

**The reason for my question is that whenever I am not sure if I am looking at a forward slash or a backslash I am trying to reason about its direction which apparently fails. I believe that this classifies it as an usability problem.**

PS: I am deriving the meanings of the directions from things like direction of writing, clock dial, rulers, time scales, calendars, play buttons etc. Left is past, back, right is future, forward.

Comment: I actually find some people calling '/' backslash. For that reason, I prefer the names Solidus and Reverse Solidus even though they are technically incorrect. A solidus is more tilted than a slash.

Comment: @Lan I imagine if you called it a Solidus in conversation you would get a lot of blank looks...

Comment: @Midas Perhaps it depends on the area. It seems like to me I have a 50/50 chance of being misinterpreted if I say "slash" or "backslash" but everyone understands that solidus is '/' and reverse solidus is '\'.

Comment: I have literally never heard it called "solidus" before. Or maybe I have and I just forgot (and will once again forget about 20 seconds after I press the "add comment" button).

Comment: @Lan interesting, where are you from if you don't mind me asking? Wikipedia gives the etymology of Solidus as British, but I'm from the UK and have never heard it called that. Perhaps for people who are old enough to remember pre-decimalisation where it was used to denote a shilling?

Comment: Pretend the slash is a pencil you're holding with the tip touching the ground. When you let go, the \ pencil falls backwards and the / pencil falls forwards.

Comment: @Midas  New Brunswick, Canada. Compute Science/Software Engineering field.

Comment: I find it annoying that "sort *ascending*" makes the results increase as they go *downward*. I suggest you get used to disappointment.

Comment: Note that for right-handed people in a left-to-right language, slashes are much easier to write than backslashes, so it makes sense to think of the back one was the weird one.

Comment: Left is not always equivalent to backwards. See http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72562/is-the-mental-model-of-time-advancing-to-the-right-in-charts-globally-accepted

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to have anything to do with UX. It asks about the history of the name for a term rather than asking about UX-related things like (1) the history/origins of its use or (2) the current terminology for an interface element with an unknown name. It might be on topic at English.SE.

Comment: @starrise But the Latin term for left handed is "sinister". So it may not be so much backward as "bad" : ) Maybe it should be called *badslash*. But that would be redundant, as slashing is already bad. Its all good, I guess.

Comment: You can argue that either slash points forward. I just call one an escape character and the other a slash. Forward and backward are too relative to be used here.

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand this community. Why is this a good ux question and receives 40 upvotes?

Comment: See also [What is the difference between “solidus” and “slash”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10993/what-is-the-difference-between-solidus-and-slash/226168)

Comment: Why is an arrow pointing forward when it has multiple points pointing backward?

Comment: @Mateo When you point your finger at someone, there are three fingers pointing back at you. *"Don't point that thing at me, it might go off!"*

Comment: @stefan.s웃 I think that UX referes to **Urgent Exasperation.**

Comment: Because slash was already taken and *reverse slash* was too long.

Comment: In the majority of languages used principally to the East of Jerusalem, would  back & forward slash definitions be swapped?

Comment: I was taught to always start a drawing a glyph at the baseline. Therefore '/' is forward. Who starts drawing glyphs from the top then accuses everyone of naming "\" backwards?

Comment: "Forward" slash also starts from left and continues to the right, so that part of your logic is invalid I would say..

Comment: It's also a graph describing an upward slope, going up to the left :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Ancient *slash* → new *back-slash* → disambiguating retronym *forward slash*

---

### Ancient Roman coins - Solidus and Denarius.

The *slash* character came first, with a different formal name *solidus*. This name comes from Latin and was associated with coinage - hence (I guess) it's use in writing down prices in older currencies: `10/6` was quite a common notation for prices in British currency pre-decimalisation. The solidus mark probably indicates the first number is units of solidus, the second of denarius. Or in the British case: shillings and pence. Note common first letter abbreviations s and d were used in Britain (also £ is L for Latin libra).

The slash (or solidus) was around for a very very long time before the reversed version was invented. The reversed version therefore acquired the more informal name back-slash to indicate a reversed form of slash.

The name "forward slash" has probably evolved since the general public started to use computer keyboards incorporating two characters that look like a slash.  There was a need to disambiguate *slash* for people who didn't learn about computers in a formal teaching context.

---

### The Medieval comma, Johannes Gutenberg and Aldus Manutius

The history of the slash and the comma are intimately intertwined. Both have been used to separate items of text or to separate numbers with different units. In some European countries it is normal to use the comma where others use a decimal point - to separate whole units from decimal fractions. So you might see €5,60 as a price. The comma serving much the same role as the slash (or solidus) in 10/6.

It is easy to find history linking the two. For [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#History)

> The [comma] mark used today is descended from a diagonal slash, or virgula suspensiva ( / ), used from the 13th to 17th centuries to represent a pause. The modern comma was first used by Aldus Manutius

I have also seen the reverse stated, that the slash is derived from the comma.

I believe that the earliest movable-type printing presses, as used by Johannes Gutenberg used commas in some situations where we would today normally use slashes. So his fonts did not have slashes, only commas.

[image: Gutenberg's font]

---

### 1899 - Adler typewriter company.

[[image]

<sup>- Photo © Dake - CC-by-SA 2.5</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout#/media/File:Typewriter_adler1_keyboard.jpg)

Slash, but no backslash.

---

### C20th - Monotype corporation

[image]
<sup>Monotype Matrix Case, Arrangement No 841</sup>

No slashes or backslashes in moveable type typography? But note the comma.

---

### 1963 - Telex

[image]
<sup>[ASR-32 teleprinter for Telex, CC BY 2.0, Arnold Reinhold](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Telex_machine_ASR-32.jpg)</sup>

Slash but no backslash.

---

### 1963 - American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII)

[American Standards Association (ASA) X3.4 subcommittee](http://worldpowersystems.com/J/codes/X3.4-1963/)

```
/   slant
...
\   reverse slant
```

---

### 1991 - [Unicode consortium](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf)

```
002F   /     SOLIDUS
             = slash, virgule

005C   \     REVERSE SOLIDUS
             = backslash.
```

---

So it is clear that the name backslash was introduced to indicate a novel character that was the reversed version of a long established character.

The name forward slash therefore subsequently became needed to disambiguate the name for the earlier character.

Comment: +1 for the linguist's answer. particularly for using the word retronym (albeit not in a sentence).

Answer (score 256):

You have a stick, |, in your mind (AKA a *pipe* character).

\ lean it back - will fall back = back slash

/ lean it forward - will fall front = forward slash

Font features can be grouped as thickness, slant and width as in Google fonts. The natural way of writing is to lean forward which is named as slant.

Slant is one of the synonyms of slash<sup>[2,3]</sup>. Here is forward-slanted natural handwriting:

[image: Forward slanted handwriting]

[2]: "slant, n.¹", Oxford English Dictionary, 1st ed., Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1911. 
  [3]: A slash by another name: http://www.kith.org/journals/neology/2011/12/a_slash_by_any_other_name.html

Comment: Indeed. It is called a back slash, because it is sloped back against the direction of writing, in contrast to the common slash. Source: https://www.wordnik.com/words/backslash

Comment: This is a useful way to remember which is which, but it does not answer the question of why the characters are named the way they are.

Comment: I feel like the pre-edit section is kind of useless; it works as a mnemonic but it doesn’t appear to be the source of the name. I want to upvote the post-edit part of the answer *only*, though even there I would like to see more evidence that this actually is the origin (though I personally suspect it is).

Comment: @KRyan The answer speaks to this statement from the OP: `whenever I am not sure if I am looking at a forward slash or a backslash I am trying to reason about its direction`

Comment: @plainclothes OK, than the two sections of the question should be labeled, so it’s clear which question each is responding to. I’d also argue that the title question’s answer should come first, but then the other concern is bolded so eh. But simply having a first, unlabeled half, and then having a second half labeled only “Edit:” is not useful, and makes this answer confusing to read.

Comment: It's only a natural slant if you're right handed. For us lefties, it's a pita scrunching so as not to smudge ink. Of course, modern biros are a lot better, but I miss cartridges.

Comment: Stack Exchange has advanced revision history built in. The word "Edit" is not needed. Posts can be edited by anyone, anytime and should be a final work, not a series of edits. If needed, someone can look at the revision history to determine the series of edits.

Comment: This answer only works if your point of origin is the bottom of the character. If like many people you think of the origin as the left then the names forward and backslash make no sense.

Comment: "you have a stick lean it to back" only works if you are holding your stick upwards, if you are holding it at the top the names should be reversed! That is the fundamental problem with this naming.

Comment: @JamesRyan there is no "holding" going on, the stick is *falling*. By definition (on this planet at least) it is touching something at the bottom, therefore falling in the direction of the text (RtoL in this part of the world) or opposite that - "back"wards. Not so complex, really, when you don't think about it. *Why has this Question gotten so much attention?* Don't we all have more important things to think about? (I don't) (yes you do) (Shh! you'll ruin the story)

Comment: It is called a back slash because it is the "opposite/mirror/complement" of a "slash".  Further, if you were looking at a keyboard the forward slash is highly suggestive of forehand and the backslash of backhand (tennis-ish analogy). We just needed a better expression than SLOSH, which was floating around in years gone by. At least most of us don't have to deal with solid and split pipes.

Comment: There is nothing "natural" about cursive writing.  It's an ugly hack that was developed to work around a very specific (and long-since obsolete) problem: Quill pens had a tendency to blot when lifted from the page, so they set up a whole new writing style that minimized the number of times you would have to lift the pen, at the severe expense of readability.

Comment: "/ lean it to forward - will fall front = forward slash"
This assumes that it is 'facing' right, and therefore that right = forward. You could make the same arbitrary assumption in the opposite direction and say '/' is falling backwards.

Comment: alwayd amazed when google is referenced when it comes to fonts... Techies, c'mon

Comment: @nocomprende: "By definition (on this planet at least) it is touching something at the bottom" - except for lines on a page, which are "hanging" down from the top (as evidenced by a paragraph that fills only half a page - it's on top of the page, not at its bottom).

Comment: Let it be known that it was in 2016 that the internet had to be reminded that once, long ago, the characters we see now on our computer screens were once drawn, literally, by hand. Those primitive beings named the backslash so because in order to draw one you had to raise your flesh from the paper with the force of 1000 keyups, move your arm BACKwards, and then strike down with the force of a form.submit()

Comment: @O.R.Mapper and also take note that the characters rest on an imaginary line, such that the x height is the height of most of the characters, which have their bottoms all on said imaginary line. A few characters are "taller" and so exceed the x height. A few have "descenders" which protrude below the imaginary baseline. When children are taught to write, they learn to write so that the characters touch the imaginary baseline at the bottom. (Think of lined paper) The top has nothing to do with it. Since we are talking about individual characters, the line formatting rules. (no pun in 10 did.)

Comment: @Bart Gijssens: that site quotes Wiktionary as its source. I would never trust Wiktionary. My guess is that the backslash simply came after the slash: http://www.bobbemer.com/BACSLASH.HTM

Comment: @reinierpost: Of course it came after the slash. But that's not the question. The question is: why are we naming it back slash and not new slash or cool slash or directory slash or  whatever. The question is about the ethymology of the word.

Comment: @Bart Gijssens: but that follows: it slants in the reverse direction. *back = reverse*

Comment: @reinierpost: So why is it not called reverse slash, or opposite slash, or mirror slash, or ...?

Comment: @reinierpost: you are actuallu close to what I believe is the correct answer. It indeed, as you say "slants in the reverse direction". This is imo correct. But in relation to the direction of writing, and not in relation to the other slash. That's where we disagree.

Answer (score 52):

Because slashes (`/`) were around long before their backwards counterpart came along.

---

EDIT:

Well, it was a nice theory, but according to Wikipedia:

- "The name **"slash"** is a recent development, first attested in American English c. 1961" [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation))
- "Bob Bemer introduced the "`\`" character into ASCII on September 18, 1961, as the result of character frequency studies." [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) [Bemer's own account](https://web.archive.org/web/20180402195951/http://www.bobbemer.com/BACSLASH.HTM)

The `/` *symbol* was around for centuries before it got this name, which (I'm guessing) contributed to it getting the unmarked **slash** name while the novel `\` got the marked **backslash** name.

Comment: True, but that does not answer the question. They could perfectly have named the new slash sorward slash and vice versa.

Comment: sorward slash? Like, a flying slash? cool...

Comment: @BartGijssens `/` is a slash. `\` is like a slash but a mirror image, i.e. backwards.  So it's a backwards slash or 'backslash'. If I said, I have this new letter that looks like a K but it's backwards, you wouldn't say, "Great let's name it the 'forwards K'".

Comment: > is greater-than, so < is back-greater-than? Because it is the opposite? Oh, I see.

Comment: < and > were presumably invented at the same time. It's more like how we'd call ? "question mark" and ¿ "upside-down question mark" because the latter are much more recent (for English speakers at least).

Comment: This really is the correct answer. Slash, with this name, existed __on keyboards and in typography__ for a very long time before the backslash character became common. It was introduced to permit printing/typing fractions on a single line -- 2/3, for example -- just as the @ character became common because it was already in use as a commercial shorthand for "each" abbreviated ea.  ("At" is a back-formation from pricing shown as "5 @ $1.00, $5.00 total". ). So slash was preexisting.When " \"  was added, there were several colloquial names for it; backslash is the one which survived.

Comment: If there were some references for this, it would be an excellent answer...

Comment: See what I added now.

Comment: Even if the name "slash" came into use a the the same time "\" entered ASCII in 1961, most people weren't using computers then and my memory is that "/" was a standard symbol on *typewriters* while "\" was a specialized computer symbol. I'm also not sure this is a usability issue as much as an issue of language which isn't designed according to usability principles.

Comment: Besides fractions, also think of the percent sign - which is a sort of abbreviation of a specialized fraction. If you saw a percent sign with the diagonal part running the same direction as a backslash, you'd know it was backwards, right?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Good point. If we are writing a fraction, the top (I hope we can agree on the definition of that word) is written first (I hope we can agree on the definition of that word too). So the percent sign looks like writing zero over zero, which of course is the case when... Uh... nevermind.

Comment: @keshlam - that's an awesome fact ('@' being originally each) - the symbol makes so much more sense if it abbreviates ea.

Answer (score 37):

This character has many different names, and *back slash* is just the oposite of *slash*, nothing else. It was initially created to represent signs in [**ALGOL language**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL) that functioned as `AND` and `OR` operators

> Bob Bemer introduced the "\" character into ASCIIon September 18,
>   1961,as the result of character frequency studies. In particular
>   the \ was introduced so that the ALGOL boolean operators ∧ (AND) and ∨
>   (OR) could be composed in ASCII as "/\" and "\/" respectively.
>   Both these operators were included in early versions of the C
>   programming language supplied with Unix V6, Unix V7 and more currently
>   BSD 2.11.

so, it has nothing to do with leaning back or forward, but it was originally conceived as just the remaining part of the [logical disjunction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)/ [conjunction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) math signs, and while its real name is **reverse solidus**, it has many different names besides **back slash**

> It is sometimes called a hack, whack, escape (from C/UNIX), reverse
>   slash, slosh, backslant, downhill, backwhack, and in rare occasions,
>   bash, reverse slant, and reversed virgule

Source: [Back Slash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash)

Comment: `it has nothing to do with leaning back or forward` < Of course it does. Just like it's alternate name "backslant" implies, it leans backward.

Comment: when I wote the answer there was only the original comment. Still, that comment and answer originated by it doesn't explain the MANY different ways to call the element. If you feel documentation is wrong, please discuss with those that actually wrote it and stop your infatuation with me

Comment: Infatuation? Not sure what you're after there. In regards to the "documentation" you made an incorrect inference based on the quotes you included. Just pointing that out. Refining answers is what makes SE work.

Comment: Yes, I see the personal opinions being upvoted, you're right. This site is getting better every day. Again, if you have problems with documented answers, go to the source, I have no time to play with you, really

Comment:  ... Grumpy today.

Comment: A backslash is not a reverse solidus. A backslash is "straighter" than a reverse solidus.

Comment: This answer really just covers the origin of the symbol itself, not the origin of the term 'Backslash'.

Comment: @JonW, backslash isn't even the 100% accepted term, just a common one, and as said in the answer and sources, it's the opposite (or mirror image) of the slash. Nothing else. I answered in terms of usability and documented history. If we're going to consider only the semiotics, then this question has to be moved to A more appropriate site like http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the post, you used `\/`, which means "escape `/`". You need to double-up the backslash. (I can't even type `\` in this comment without this happening!)`

Comment: @Lan The official, formal Unicode for the \ is REVERSE SOLIDUS, and Unicode does not have a character with the name BACKSLASH.

Comment: @MrLister Actually, I typed `\`\\`` without escaping it, and it glitched.

Comment: @MrLister I didn't know unicode conflated them. Thanks. Wikipedia says "The solidus is similar to another punctuation mark, the slash, which is found on standard keyboards; the slash is closer to being vertical than the solidus. These are two distinct symbols that have entirely different uses. "

Answer (score 27):

The reason you're confused is because you're using the wrong definition of "back". Or rather, the wrong reference frame to apply the word "back" to.

You are apparently using the direction of writing, that is to say from left to right, to apply the word "back" to. But in terms of direction, the word "back" has two meaning:

1. The opposite of "forward".
2. Opposite or reverse.

The word "back", apart from meaning the opposite of forward, actually itself can simply mean "the opposite direction".

### There is no "Forward Slash"

Technically, "forward slash" did not exist. It only came about retroactively after the term "backslash" was coined. The original name for "forward slash" was simply **"slash"**. It is with reference to **slash** that the word "back" was applied. It simply means **"reverse slash"**.

### Back to your problem

So, if backslash means reverse-slash, how to know which direction "slash" slants to?

I don't really know much about your culture but for me slashes are what we use to write dates and street addresses:

```
date: 1/1/2016
place: No. 10, 14/24 street, Section 14, Petaling Jaya.
```

So that's what I use to remember "slash" - it's what people normally use: "/". So "backslash" is what people don't normally use" "\".

Comment: Reverse-Slash is The Slash's greatest enemy.

Comment: @JohnClifford yeah, if you put them together, they annihilate: **X**

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that slash is also commonly used in fractions: 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, etc.?

Comment: @RobertFisher: Yeah, I wasn't sure if that style of writing fractions is recent development (influenced by the divide operator in programming languages?). Traditionally I'd write a fraction with a horizontal line rather than a slash.

Comment: @slebetman Fair point. The wikipedia article suggests that it was adopted from using a solidus between shillings and pence. Although I (a child of the 1970s) saw these style of fractions long before I was introduced to ones with a horizontal line in math class (c. ?) or the division operator in programming (c. 1979). So, I assumed it was old enough to be familiar to most.

Comment: +1 for nixing "forward slash". Of course, that won't stop it from being used, and perhaps even becoming the most commonly used name...

Comment: God Almighty! I thought I was writing **Slashes** when I learned handwriting as a child, but all along I was actually writing a **Solidus**! How could I be that idiotic??? I'm sari I was sarong! And I didn't know I was writing a programming division operator for fractions (before the personal computer had been invented). Forgive me! So bad person. I'll never type the wrong version of that character again. Now, how do I get the actual Unicode approved version to come out here? 7 keystrokes instead of 1? No Problem!!!

Comment: @slebetman: If a fraction is intended to be read as part of a line of text, writing it as ²/₃ will allow the reader's eye to move in a consistent left-to-right direction.  Stacking it perfectly vertically would require the reader's eye to backtrack after reading the numerator.

Answer (score 11):

The verb *to slash* [comes from the Middle French esclachier](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=slash&allowed_in_frame=0) and means to cut with a single sweeping motion. If you hold a knife or sword and slash something in front of you like a curtain or an enemy, and you are right handed like most people, the wound will be from top right to bottom left. Think of the middle part of the Z in Zorro.

*Back* means the other way.

Comment: Yeah, but the wound will start at the person's *left* shoulder... See? We have been looking at this from *our* point of view all along, when we should have been taking the *character's* point of view. No wonder writing is so hard to understand! We have been reading it **backwards**! Er, I mean, the wrong way round.

Answer (score 5):

My mnemonic for recalling this is to visualize the slash as a person viewed from the side. The person would face forward in the direction of reading with the head at the top and feet at the bottom of the written line. A pipe `|` stands straight while a backslash `\` leans back.

Alternatively I (dimly) recall that a slash follows handwritten forward slanting, and a backslash crosses that, as has been mentioned.

Comment: This is how I used to teach it.  History completely aside this helped English speaking students remember it so they could follow spoken instructions.

Comment: That's a very dextrous explanation :-). When you say "from the side" you assume without noticing that this means "from their right side". A more sinister or gauche observer may visualise viewing said person from their left side :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thats dumb because the "person" wouldnt be walking against the flow of the text

Comment: @StevenPenny Without desiring to be confrontational - Labelling something as "dumb" often can mean that one does not see things in the way described and cannot imagine that anyone else would either. In such cases, "smart" MIGHT be seeing that some people may see & think quite differently, even though it does not seem to make sense. (People tend to be like that :-) ). | What seems to be an excellent example of this is given in the OP's original question. His description of why he sees a  \ as a forward-slash is utterly foreign to my way of thinking - but this whole discussion arises from that.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yeah, you are on to something. We should be viewing the text from what we would call "behind it" and looking outward toward the reader's eyes. In that way, the text direction would still be "forward", except that it would go to the left now... So, it appears that some people are actually "inside" their computers, which leads to the different views on this question. Of course, it is bigoted to call something "inside" or "outside", as it presumes a preferred viewpoint. Best not to say anything at all.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Although "from the side" appears at the end of a sentence, it is not the whole of the description. I do not merely imply the right hand side, I actually go on to say this "person would face forward in the direction of reading" by which I mean left to right for English, and so I am quite explicit about which side of the imaginary person I am talking about. I'm not trying to be dexter-centric; I feel like you jumped on this without a complete reading.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Indeed.  I once had a conversation about odd vs. even numbers with someone who said that she recognized an even number as being something divisible by two.  I was the opposite -- a number is divisible by two if it's even!  Different people can take *completely* opposite paths on even simple problems!

Comment: Presumably in the majority of languages used principally to the East of Jerusalem back & forward slash definitions would be swapped.
 :-) :-) :-) :-) :-) :-)  <- ie It's a joke. | [fwiw: I TRY, within sensible limits,  to read things as many times as it takes to make the writers intention clear. ]

Answer (score 4):

If you are right handed, `\` is annoying to write, while `/` is easier, which is why `/` became the separator symbol of choice in the days before computers and typewriters. It came to be called slash. In a UX sense, the canonical name is given to the more common variant, which is more common because it is more ergonomic.

`\` looks like the a slash that's backwards, so presumably this is why it came to be called a backslash.

> Why is backslash called BACK slash when arguably it points forward?

I would be very frightened of encountering these supposed persons who engage in arguments over which way the backslash points.

But in any case, the point is not which way it points. The symbols are opposites of each other, so you pick a dominant one and define the other in relation to the dominant. Clearly `/` makes more sense to choose as the dominant symbol: It is easier to write, it is more common, it has more meanings and is appropriate in more contexts than `\`, not to mention that it is older.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is hidden in the mists of time, but I, your intrepid explorer, have braved the journey<sup>[1]</sup> and returned to supply you with the One True Etymology for "backslash".

---

<sup>[1] I have not literally traveled back in time.</sup>

---

It all starts with the shilling. You remember the shilling, if you were born before circa 1970. The British unit of currency used to be the pound sterling, which was divided into twenty shillings. Each shilling was further divided into twelve pence. There were also one-hundred-twenty ha'pence to a crown, one-thousand-eight farthings to a guinea,… but I digress. (In case you were wondering what J.K. Rowling was spoofing with her seventeen sickles to a galleon and twenty-nine knuts to a sickle, now you know.)

The common way of referring to a quantity of currency less than a pound was with the word "and". For example, two shillings and threepence would be called "two and three". This was written with a `/` mark, for example `2/3`.

Now, the `&` got angry. It had long been used for "and", and it maintained that if people say "two and three" then they should write `2&3`. It went over to the `2/3` and tried to pull the `/` out. But the figures (digits) liked the `/`: it was nice and slender, and they were afraid that they would be too crowded with an `&`. So they hung on to the `/`, not allowing the `&` to pull it out.

So the `&` came up with another plan. It went to the Queen and tried to plead its case. It wanted the government to introduce a public bill to Parliament mandating that shillings-and-pence amounts be written using `&` only and never `/`. The Queen thought it was a grand idea and set her Chancellor of the Exchequer, Peter Thorneycroft, on it.

Well, the bill failed to pass. But while it was in process in Parliament, Thorneycroft got really into the idea, and set about enforcing it before it even became law. (This is why he wound up resigning his position.) He sent his employees around to all the shops with instructions to whip the chest of anyone who was seen writing `2/3`. The chest was chosen because it was most convenient: the government employee was in front of the person, so he could see him writing, so he whipped his front.

At that time, the `/` became known as a "front's lash". So naturally the `\` was called a "back's lash".

Answer (score -1):

It's simple, the 'slash' / came first. Then keyboards & computers came up with one that pointed the other direction. So, what to call it? BACKSLASH \

Computers used it and 'invented' it because they wanted a character that was NOT currently being used in normal language.

Comment: -1 because this not only repeats what other "answers" have already said, but it also fails to provide any historical evidence.

Answer (score -2):

I think in this case of a Forward Slash or Backslash, it is seen basically from the POV of:

/ = Forward Slash -> top pointing right, so "forward"

\ = Backslash  -> top pointing left, so "backward"

I think it has to do with the western left-to- right reading custom as well as the human experience of gravity:

If the Slash was a stick, a Forward Slash would fall towards the right, while a Backslash would fall towards the left

Comment: -1 because this not only repeats what other "answers" have already said, but it also fails to provide any historical evidence.

Comment: historical evidence? Only one answer even attempts to that direction, and even he doesn't provide "evidence"... Whatever...